# Am I doing async/await correctly?

Tags: c#, task, .net-4.5, async-await

I'm trying to use `async` and `await` keywords for the first time and I have a doubt whether I'm doing this correctly.

In my WPF form's `Loaded` event I use a method:

```
private void MessagesWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridMessagesLoadAsync();
}
```

Which looks like this:

```
private async void DataGridMessagesLoadAsync()
{
    _messages = await _messageService.GetAllMessagesAsync();
    dataGridMessages.ItemsSource = _messages;
    if (_messages.Count() == 0) return;
    dataGridMessages.Columns[6].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    dataGridMessages.Columns[8].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    dataGridMessages.Columns[10].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    dataGridMessages.Columns[11].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    dataGridMessages.Columns[12].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

The `GetAllMessagesAsync()` looks like this:

```
public async Task<List<Message>> GetAllMessagesAsync()
{
    return (from m in _context.Messages select m).ToList();
}
```

I'm not sure whether I get any asynchrony - it seems like the whole window is waiting for the `DataGrid`, but my data is so small that I can't figure out whether it's just my computer lag or really the `DataGrid`. What's more, Visual Studio gives a warning:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run
>   synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
>   non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work
>   on a background
>   thread.

So I understand I would have to await something in `GetAllMessagesAsync()`? But what? And the new function would have to await some other `async` function as well? I can't figure it out, I get into an infinite loop in my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just return a `Task` directly:

```
public Task<List<Message>> GetAllMessagesAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _context.Messages.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now the it's clearly visible the UI is not blocked. However, should the be named `GetAllMessagesAsync()` or `GetAllMessages()`? According to the naming convention proposed by Microsoft all the methods with `async` keyword should have such suffix but if there's no such modifier?

Comment: @vtvs - I believe the convention is to use the Async suffix for methods which return a `Task`, the use of `async` is an implementation detail.